# Stop a TimerTask without stopping the Timer

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I have a `Timer` and I schedule a task for it at a certain fixed rate, using the method `scheduleAtFixedRate`. The problem is that after some actions, i want to finish/cancel this task that was scheduled before.

**I know that i can use `.cancel()` or `.purge()`** but that will cancel/finish my timer, which is something that i don't want to. I just want to finish the task.

Does any of you know how to do this ?

This is my code (I have the `Timer` created as a field of the class)

```
receiveTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int fileSize=(int)fileSizeToReceive;
            int actual= totalReceived;

            ((Notification.Builder) mBuilderReceive).setContentText("Receiving  "+actualNameToReceive);
            ((Notification.Builder) mBuilderReceive).setProgress(fileSize, actual, false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(id, ((Notification.Builder) mBuilderReceive).getNotification());
        }
    },0,500);//delay, interval
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hold a reference to your `TimerTask` so you can call `cancel()` on it whenever you'd like.

Calling `cancel()` on the `TimerTask` will not stop the `Timer`.

For example, declare your task:

```
TimerTask task;
```

Initialize and schedule it:

```
task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int fileSize=(int)fileSizeToReceive;
        int actual= totalReceived;

        ((Notification.Builder) mBuilderReceive)
            .setContentText("Receiving  "+actualNameToReceive);
        ((Notification.Builder) mBuilderReceiver)
            .setProgress(fileSize, actual, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, ((Notification.Builder) mBuilderReceive)
            .getNotification());
    }
};

receiveTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 500);
```

To stop it, you just have to call `cancel()` on the task instance:

```
task.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

`boolean isStop = false;`

```
 receiveTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
         public void run() {

          if(!isStop){

            int fileSize=(int)fileSizeToReceive;
            int actual= totalReceived;

            ((Notification.Builder) mBuilderReceive).setContentText("Receiving  "+actualNameToReceive);
            ((Notification.Builder) mBuilderReceive).setProgress(fileSize, actual, false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(id, ((Notification.Builder) mBuilderReceive).getNotification());
          }
        }
    },0,500);//delay, interval
```

when you dont want execute the code set `isStop = true`

Comment: Well I think this would continue to execute the timer, thought the code wont get executed.